# Histogram, QQPlot, y BoxPlot en R y Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, r, python-2.7, plot

***Hola! Quisiera tener Histogram, QQPlot, y BoxPlot un plot a lado de otro, porque así es más fácil analizar esa variable en particular. Tampoco quiero usar el nombre de una columna, sino hacer un loop por todas las variables numéricas. Es decir quiero plots de todas las variables numéricas del data.frame. Necesito hacerlo tanto en R como en Python.***

En R lo he logrado, me parece, con el código que está a continuación. Luego de correrlo en RStudio, moviendo la flecha a la izquierda del panel de plots, los 3 plots de la misma variable están uno a continuación de otro.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

data(penguins)

df=penguins

df_numerical <- df %>% select(where(is.numeric))

lapply(names(df_numerical), function(col) {
  qqnorm(df_numerical[[col]], pch = 1, main = col, xlab= col, col="darkmagenta")
  qqline(df_numerical[[col]], col = "red", lwd = 2)
  hist(df_numerical[[col]], main = col, xlab= col, col="lightblue")
  boxplot(df_numerical[[col]], main = col, xlab=col, col="lightyellow", horizontal = TRUE, border = "brown", notch = TRUE)})
```

***En Python***, mi código funciona bastante bien porque logra hacer casi todo. Sin embargo, tiene dos problemas:

1. La línea roja de los QQPlots no aparece en todos los plots, que en cambio si aparece en R.
2. Me gustaría **si fuese posible**, en lugar de usar 3 bloques de código, uno para histograma, un segundo para qqplot, y un tercero para boxplot horizontal, usar 1 bloque de código, ***similar a lo q tiene el código en R.***

Mi pregunta es:
***Cómo podría mejorar mi código en Python y en R?***
Muchas gracias por anticipado!
Un lindo día!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

#PRIMERO NO OLVIDES
#pip install palmerpenguins

import scipy
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
from palmerpenguins import load_penguins
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

penguins = load_penguins()
df=penguins
df_numerical=df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)

for col in df_numerical.columns:
    one_column_df = pd.DataFrame(df_numerical[col])
    
    for col in one_column_df.columns:
        print()
        print(col)
        ax1=sns.histplot(data=one_column_df, x=col)
        plt.show()
    for col in one_column_df.columns:
        print()
        print(col)
        ax2=stats.probplot(one_column_df.loc[:,col], dist="norm", plot=plt)
        plt.show()
    for col in one_column_df.columns:
        print()
        print(col)
        ax3=sns.boxplot(data=one_column_df.loc[:,col], orient="h")
        plt.show()
```

***Siempre publico una pregunta para Python y otra para R. En este caso lo hice así porque me pareció que publicar ambas ilustra el problema que tengo.***

Comment: Buen día, veo que hay varias preguntas: 1. ¿Cómo mejorar el código en R? 2. ¿Cómo mostrar todos los QQPlots en python? 3. ¿Cómo mejorar el código en python? Es mejor que enfoques tu pregunta a un solo tema ya que de otra forma no se apega a los lineamientos de [so.es] y además será más complicado que un solo usuario provea una respuesta completa por lo que será más difícil que aceptes una respuesta como válida. Tal como está la pregunta corre el riesgo de quedar abierta para siempre o no recibir la atención que esperas. Por favor edita tu pregunta y describe un único problema.

Comment: Lo mejor sería que hicieras por lo menos 2 preguntas separadas (Una para Python y otra para R). Te recomendaría editar tu pregunta y enfocar esta al tema que tenga mayor prioridad. Publiqué una respuesta para la parte de Python pero la he ocultado momentáneamente ya que no sé si esta pregunta se va a enfocar a Python o R.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Hola! Siempre publico una pregunta para Python y otra para R. En este caso lo hice así porque me pareció que publicar ambas ilustra el problema que tengo. Siempre acepto la respuesta que aporte más. Estoy interesado en respuestas en Python, en R, o en ambos lenguajes de programación. Todas mis preguntas aceptan una respuesta. Por favor publica tu respuesta. Inicié la recompensa el Viernes. Siempre acepto una respuesta antes de los 7 días que dura la recompensa para que los puntos vayan a la mejor respuesta.

Comment: Parte fundamental del funcionamiento del sitio es que las preguntas tengan un solo tema, eso ayuda a otros usuarios con preguntas similares a poder encontrar respuestas a sus problemas. Cuando una pregunta incluye más de un tema entonces se vuelve inválida para otros usuarios ya que se trataría de un caso muy específico y lo que se busca es que tanto los problemas como las soluciones se puedan aplicar a otros escenarios. El problema no es que aceptes o no las respuestas sino que se pueda re-utilizar para otros usuarios

Comment: Por favor limítala a un solo tema, de lo contrario podría terminar cerrada y/o con votos negativos.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Comprendo tu punto de vista, pero no lo comparto. En este caso hay solamente un tema: Histogram, QQPlot, y BoxPlot un plot a lado de otro.

Comment: [Continuemos la conversación en el chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246299/histogram-qqplot-y-boxplot-en-r-y-python)

Comment: @HeytalePazguato Si hubieras hecho la sugerencia antes de iniciar al recompensa, lo hubiera hecho. Pero, ahora no me parece una buena idea. Muchas veces hay opiniones diferentes. Por favor no te ofendas.

Comment: Una pregunta que dice como mejorar, es una pregunta basada en opiniones. Que es lo que queres mejorar? memoria? velocidad? y entonces es la discusion de que es mejor..  Y ademas, incluye como bien te dijeron 2 lenguajes distintos, con lo cual si tenes una respuesta en R y otra en python, cual vas a aceptar?

Comment: @gbianchi Voy a aceptar la q aporte más. Para la próxima haré una pregunta en cada lenguaje. Desafortunadamente, la excelente sugerencia llegó cuando ya había comenzado la recompensa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

No hace falta que crees tantos ciclos `for` para crear tus gráficas, eso solo hace el proceso más lento.

**Nota:** No quise instalar `palmerpenguins` así que obtengo el mismo `dataset` desde seaborn con `sns.load_dataset('penguins')`

La razón por la que no sale la línea roja de las gráficas de probabilidad es porque existen valores `NaN` (Del inglés Not a Number) en el `dataset` que estás utilizando, hay dos opciones, eliminar las filas que tengan `NaN` o asignar `0` a todos los `NaN` (Yo opté por eliminar los `NaN`).

Y lo único que hay que hacer es graficar `df_numerical[col]`

Ejemplo completo:

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
#from palmerpenguins import load_penguins
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

#penguins = load_penguins()

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
df=penguins
df_numerical=df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)

# Eliminar los NaN
df_numerical = df_numerical.dropna()

# Crear una figura con subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df_numerical.columns), ncols=3, figsize=(25,15))

# Crear los subplots
for i,col in enumerate(df_numerical.columns):
    sns.histplot(df_numerical[col], ax = ax[i][0])
    stats.probplot(df_numerical[col], plot=ax[i][1])
    # Quitar el título "Probability plot"
    ax[i][1].set_title('')
    sns.boxplot(data = df_numerical[col], orient='h', ax = ax[i][2])

plt.show()
```

Esto devuelve las siguientes gráficas:

[image: Gráficas]

Si quisieras crear gráficas separadas para cada columna de tu `dataframe` entonces puedes crear la figura con los subplots adentro del ciclo `for` y cambiar el `layout` a 1 renglón y 3 columnas y también hay que mover `plt.show()` adentro del ciclo `for`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
#from palmerpenguins import load_penguins
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

#penguins = load_penguins()

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
df=penguins
df_numerical=df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)

# Eliminar los NaN
df_numerical = df_numerical.dropna()

# Crear las gráficas
for i,col in enumerate(df_numerical.columns):
    # Crear una figura con sub plots
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(20,5))
    
    sns.histplot(df_numerical[col], ax = ax[0])
    stats.probplot(df_numerical[col], plot=ax[1])
    # Quitar el título "Probability plot"
    ax[1].set_title('')
    sns.boxplot(data = df_numerical[col], orient='h', ax = ax[2])
    
    # Mostrar plot
    plt.show()
```

Esto devuelve las mismas gráficas mostradas anteriormente pero cada fila es una gráfica separada (En lugar de tener una figura con 4 filas y 3 columnas se tendrían 4 figuras, cada una con una fila y 3 columnas).

Comment: Fantástica respuesta! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Publiqué una nueva pregunta sobre Python. Si pudieses ayudarme, aquí está el link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547071/r-correlation-plots-en-python

Answer (score 2):

El enfoque en R está listo, lo único que debes agregar antes es:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3) # uno al lado del otro

# lapply(...
```

ó

```
par(mfrow = c(3,1) # uno sobre el otro

# lapply(...
```

Siguiendo la forma `(número de fila, número de columnas)`

Comment: Excelente mejora! Muchas gracias!