# R Correlation Plots en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, r, pandas, rstudio

Estoy trantando de hacer algo así en Python. Al menos lo más cercano posible. Lo ideal sería un solo gráfico, pero si no se puede, lo acepto en multiples gráficos, o en una combinación de gráficos y tablas. ***Lo que es muy importante, es no usar nunca el nombre de ninguna columna, por cuanto estoy tratando en tener una solución que pueda aplicar a otros datasets.*** De antemano, muchísimas gracias por su ayuda!

Solamente como un ejemplo, estoy usando el dataset "penguins." Este es el modelo "ideal". Fue logrado en ***R*** con el paquete ***PerformanceAnalytics*** y la función **chart.Correlation**. Este es el código en ***R***:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
data(penguins)
df=penguins
df %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% chart.Correlation(histogram = T, pch =19)
```

[image: R Correlation Plot]

Lo q he logrado en Python es lo siguiente:

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
df=penguins
df_numerical=df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)

# Eliminar los NaN
df_numerical = df_numerical.dropna()
#seaborn.PairGrid
g = sns.PairGrid(df_numerical, diag_sharey=False, corner=True)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)
g.add_legend()

#correlation matrix
df_numerical.corr()
```

[image: Python Correlation Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Para lograrlo hay que hacer un poco de "magia" ya que no hay una forma directa de hacerlo

La razón por la que no te aparecen los gráficos de la esquina superior es porque pusiste el argumento `corner = True`. En la [documentación](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) se menciona que `corner` es para hacer un gráfico de "corner" o esquina, es decir, solo la diagonal y el triángulo inferior.

Otro punto importante, parece ser que en `R` el `dataset` incluye años o alguna columna de fecha que no pude encontrar en `Python`. Las columnas que aparecen al importar el `dataset` desde `seaborn` son:

```
Index(['species', 'island', 'bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm',
       'flipper_length_mm', 'body_mass_g', 'sex'], dtype='object')
```

Por lo tanto el resultado final incluye 16 gráficas (4 filas y 4 columnas)

En lugar del estilo `whitegrid` que estabas utilizando lo cambié por `white` para que el resultado se vea lo más parecido posible al resultado de `R`

Dentro de `PairGrid` hay un argumento para eliminar los `NaN` así que utilizo ese argumento en lugar de la línea `df_numerical = df_numerical.dropna()`.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es crear el `PairGrid`:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df_numerical, diag_sharey = False, despine = False, dropna = True)
```

Para el triángulo inferior se puede utilizar `regplot` en lugar de `scatterplot` para poder obtener la línea fácilmente:

```
g.map_lower(sns.regplot, lowess=True, ci=False, line_kws={'color': 'red', 'lw': 1}, scatter_kws={'color': 'black', 's': 20})
```

Para el histograma hay dos opciones:

1. Utilizar [`distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html). Esta opción sería la más fácil de implementar pero `distplot` va a ser eliminada, si el código lo necesitas para algún trabajo o investigación para un futuro cercano tal vez sea lo mejor ya que no hay que configurar muchas cosas.

```
g.map_diag(sns.distplot, color='black', kde_kws={'color': 'red', 'cut': 0.7, 'lw': 1}, hist_kws={'histtype': 'bar', 'lw': 2, 'edgecolor': 'k', 'facecolor':'grey'})
```

2. Utilizar [`histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) y definir el color de línea con `set_color`. Si el código tiene que ser a "prueba del futuro", es decir, poder ser utilizado en un futuro lejano así como actualmente, pero para que se viera exactamente igual que la opción 1 tendrías que invertir más tiempo (No configuré todo para que se vea exactamente igual, sólo para que se vea bien).

Como `histplot` no permite crear la línea de un color diferente al histograma (Que yo creo está mal, hay [reportes de error](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2344) pero los desarrolladores no lo quieren cambiar), cree una función para poder crear el histograma de color gris y la línea roja, además le agregamos los nombres de las columnas para que se vea más cercano al resultado de `R`.

```
# Creamos una función para graficar el histograma
def histogram(x, **kws):
    ax = sns.histplot(x=x, color='grey', kde=True)
    ax.lines[0].set_color('red')
    ax.annotate(x.name, xy=(0.05, 0.9), xycoords=ax.transAxes, fontweight='bold')

g.map_diag(histogram)
```

Y por último, para las gráficas superiores creamos dos funciones para mostrar la correlación y las anotaciones con los asteriscos

```
def corrdot(*args, **kwargs):
    corr_r = args[0].corr(args[1], 'pearson')
    corr_text = round(corr_r, 2)
    ax = plt.gca()
    font_size = abs(corr_r) * 80 + 5
    ax.annotate(corr_text, [.5, .5,],  xycoords="axes fraction", ha='center', va='center', fontsize=font_size)

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r, p = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    p_stars = ''
    if p <= 0.05:
        p_stars = '*'
    if p <= 0.01:
        p_stars = '**'
    if p <= 0.001:
        p_stars = '***'
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate(p_stars, xy=(0.5, 0.6), xycoords=ax.transAxes, color='red', fontsize=70)

g.map_upper(corrdot)
g.map_upper(corrfunc)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
df=penguins
df_numerical=df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)

sns.set(style='white')

# Creamos una función para graficar el histograma
def histogram(x, **kws):
    ax = sns.histplot(x=x, color='grey', kde=True)
    ax.lines[0].set_color('red')
    ax.annotate(x.name, xy=(0.05, 0.9), xycoords=ax.transAxes, fontweight='bold')

def corrdot(*args, **kwargs):
    corr_r = args[0].corr(args[1], 'pearson')
    corr_text = round(corr_r, 2)
    ax = plt.gca()
    font_size = abs(corr_r) * 80 + 5
    ax.annotate(corr_text, [.5, .5,],  xycoords="axes fraction", ha='center', va='center', fontsize=font_size)

def corrfunc(x, y, **kws):
    r, p = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
    p_stars = ''
    if p <= 0.05:
        p_stars = '*'
    if p <= 0.01:
        p_stars = '**'
    if p <= 0.001:
        p_stars = '***'
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate(p_stars, xy=(0.5, 0.6), xycoords=ax.transAxes, color='red', fontsize=70)

g = sns.PairGrid(df_numerical, diag_sharey = False, despine = False, dropna = True)

g.map_lower(sns.regplot, lowess=True, ci=False, line_kws={'color': 'red', 'lw': 1}, scatter_kws={'color': 'black', 's': 20})

# "distplot" será eliminada en un futuro, dejo la siguiente linea para que pruebes la diferencia
#g.map_diag(sns.distplot, color='black', kde_kws={'color': 'red', 'cut': 0.7, 'lw': 1}, hist_kws={'histtype': 'bar', 'lw': 2, 'edgecolor': 'k', 'facecolor':'grey'})

g.map_diag(histogram)
g.map_upper(corrdot)
g.map_upper(corrfunc)

# Elimina espacio entre gráficas
g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

# Quitamos las etiquetas con los nombres de las gráficas
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_xlabel('')
```

Esto devuelve la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica de correlación]

Comment: Como dicen los Argentinos, "Sos un genio!"